# Find out in Perl and Windows if a file is writeable/ removable

Tags: perl, file, winapi, change-notification

I would like to build in Perl under Windows a *Watch-Dog* for a *Hot-Folder* (I might call it *Folder-Watch* or, hmm, probably much better: a **Hot-Dog**).
So far I succeeded in exactly doing that, with [`Win32::ChangeNotify`](https://metacpan.org/module/Win32::ChangeNotify) (see sample below).

But as you might guess reading the source code I ran into a problem when the moving process wants to finish when the copying/creating process of the file in `$watchdir` has not finished (*No such file or directory*).

```
use Win32::ChangeNotifier;
use File::Copy qw(move);

my $notify = Win32::ChangeNotify->new($watchdir, 0, "FILE_NAME");
while (1) {
  if ($notify->wait(1_000)) {  # 1-second wait cycle
    notify->reset;
    @foundfiles = File::get_by_ext($watchdir, "csv");  # search and return files in $watchdir with extension "csv"
    print "Something has happened! (del/ren/create)\n";
    foreach (@foundfiles) {
      move($watchdir.$_, $someotherdir.$_) or die "Fehler: $!"; 
    }
    @foundfiles = ();
  }
}
```

Is there a way to automatically find out if the file is ready to go, i.e. has been finally created/copied?

I was thinking about something like

```
while (1) {
  move $file if (-w $file)  # writeable
  wait(1)
}
```

but that does not seem to work under Windows. I need to solve this under Windows as well as Perl. Other than that I am open to suggestions.

Comment: Hmm, maybe by checking if I can open the file with a filehandle...!?

Comment: `sub writeable { open my $fh, ">>", shift }` `:)`

Comment: I don't know why you think `-w` should tell you noone's writing to a file. There might be OS-specific ways of checking if a file is in use, but I'm not aware of them.

Comment: Files should be moved into `$watchdir` atomically using `rename`. If they are copied into `$watchdir`, your best option might be to keep checking the file size until it stops changing for a 15 seconds (or whatever).

Comment: Assuming that `move` does a `rename` in your case, it works better on unix systems since unix systems allow a file name to be deleted/changed without affecting any handles to the referenced file.

Comment: Windows based file `open` plonks a mandatory lock on it, so move type operations will fail. Unix locks are advisory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! I solved it (thanks to Сухой27)!

Inserting the following code right before moving the file:

```
while (1) {
    last if writeable($path_in.$_);
    print "-";
    $| = 1;
    sleep(1);
}
```

...whereas `writeable` refers to this little sub-marine:

```
sub writeable {
    return open(my $file, ">>", shift);
}
```

Thanks, and have a nive day! :-)